# out of range exception but index is in range! wp 7.1

Tags: windows-phone-7

Ever since I converted my project from the 7.0 to 7.1, I have been getting really weird errors.  for instance:

```
List<bool> locks = new List<bool>(11);
locks[0] = true;
```

it throws an argument out of range exception on the second line, but when i put my mouse on locks it shows it has 11 elements all of which are initialized to false.

Comment: Don't do much with wp7 development, but unless it uses a slightly different version of List<T> than the full version of .NET, you are getting the out of range exception because the constructor overload List<T>(Int32) does not add that many elements.  It just initializes the backing array inside the class to 11 elements.  So you are calling an index 0 that doesn't exist yet

Comment: I thought I had used this same code in other places and it worked, but looking back I used add before.

You are right.  I guess I was confused because it shows there are 11 bool objects in the list with boolean values, not 11 nulls.

Comment: Yeah, I just looked up the List<T> in the Silverlight framework and the behavior is the same as .NET 4.0.  I'll make my comment an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just looked up the MSDN entry for [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw8e0z9z%28v=vs.95%29) in the Silverlight Framework.  If the code you posted is your exact code, you are getting the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` because the index does not exist.

Your constructor `List<bool> locks = new List<bool>(11);` is creating a new List with 0 elements, but an initial capacity of 11.

When you call `locks[0] = true;`, you are trying to access an element that was not yet added, so the exception is thrown.

Based on your comment, it looks like you are seeing 11 bool's in the list.  Unless you have more code between the 2 lines, that isn't possible.

Using the debugger, if you dig deep enough into the object, you are going to see the backing array for the `List<bool>`, which will have 11 elements.  But the `List` itself doesn't have any elements.  You can easily verify this by calling `List.Count`

And you'll never see `null` in a bool value anywhere.  `bool` is a value type with a default value of false, that is why the backing array is showing 11 elements all false.